# First element of a path in python

Tags: python, path, portability

I got a list of paths and I need to extract the first element of each path in a portable way,
how would I do that?

```
['/abs/path/foo',
 'rel/path',
 'just-a-file']
```

to

```
['abs', 'rel', 'just-a-file']
```

Thanks in advance
Oli

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [69]: import os

In [70]: paths
Out[70]: ['/abs/path/foo', 'rel/path', 'just-a-file']

In [71]: [next(part for part in path.split(os.path.sep) if part) for path in paths]
Out[71]: ['abs', 'rel', 'just-a-file']
```

Comment: Thats not portable, consider a path like "C:\Users\foo" which should result in "Users", but with your solution it wont.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the drives, call `os.path.splitdrive(p)[1]` on each of the paths beforehand. (BTW, you never specified what you wanted done in the case of drive letters in the original post. Don't expect us to read your mind.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a library call to handle splitting paths in a platform independent way but it only splits into two parts:

```
import os.path

def paths(p) :
  head,tail = os.path.split(p)
  components = []
  while len(tail)>0:
    components.insert(0,tail)
    head,tail = os.path.split(head)
  return components

for p in ['/abs/path/foo','rel/path','just-a-file'] :
  print paths(p)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using newer pathlib method...

```
import PurePath from pathlib
import os

# Separates the paths into parts and prints to the console...
def print_path_parts(path: str):

    path = PurePath(path)
    parts = list(path.parts)

    # From your description, looks like you don't want the root.
    # Pop it off.
    if parts[0] == os.sep:
        parts.pop(0)

    print(parts)

# Array of path strings...
paths = ['/abs/path/foo',
         'rel/path',
         'just-a-file']

# For each path, print parts to the console
for path in paths:
    print_path_parts(path)
```

Output:

```
['abs', 'path', 'foo']
['rel', 'path']
['just-a-file']
```

Answer (score -5):

Why not just use a regex?

```
>>> import re
>>> paths = ['/abs/path/foo',
...          'rel/path',
...          'just-a-file']
>>> 
>>> [re.match(r'\/?([^\/]+)', p).groups()[0] for p in paths]
['abs', 'rel', 'just-a-file']
```

and for Windows:

```
>>> paths = [r'\abs\path\foo',
...          r'rel\path',
...          r'just-a-file',
...          r'C:\abs\path\foo',
...          r'C:rel\path',
...          r'C:just-a-file']
>>> 
>>> [re.match(r'(?:[A-Za-z]:)?\\?([^\\]+)', p).groups()[0] for p in paths]
['abs', 'rel', 'just-a-file', 'abs', 'rel', 'just-a-file']
```